# How to set a default field in a serializer to be the same as another field in the same serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer like this

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
   anotherId = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default = ????)
```

and i want to set field 'anotherId' same as 'id' by default.

This is what I expect

```
s = SomeSerializer(data={}).
data = s.data
data.id # return '56e34c58-be7d-4c7c-992a-43080faf5614'
data.anotherId #  return '56e34c58-be7d-4c7c-992a-43080faf5614' (as id)
```

I tried to do it like here but it didn't work

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
       anotherId = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default = id.get_default())
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) method for that:

```py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Model):
  id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
  another_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    if not data.get('another_id', None):
      data['another_id'] = data['id']
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to save those IDs on a model then you could achieve it using `ModelSerializer` and `pre_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/):

```py
# serializers.py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Model):
 id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
 another_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=False)

 class Meta
   model = MyModel

# models.py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

...

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def set_default_another_id(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if not instance.another_id:
    instance.another_id = instance.id
```

Comment: I am not going to save this in the model. This serializer is used just to map request data. I want the fields 'id' and 'anotherId to be generated with the same value unless the client specifies otherwise.